# Is he "a hero" or "hero"?

Tags: grammar, articles

> Edward Snowden's leak of classified government documents has provoked mixed reactions: is Snowden **hero** or traitor, patriot or coward?

So is *hero* here used as an adjective? If not why is there no article?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary before posting this question?

Answer (score 3):

*Hero, traitor, patriot,* and *coward* are all nouns and are used as such.

As I read it, the clause mimics a newspaper headline - *Snowden: Hero or Traitor? Patriot or Coward?* The choice to drop the articles is a stylistic one. It's used to draw the reader's attention to the ongoing, sensationalized discourse among the public and media.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is ontological. Adding an article shifts the meaning. It is used here in an abstract sense as in 'war is peace'.

Snowden = hero? 
vs.
Snowden := hero?

The source of the phrase is an academic class at Stanford University: "Heroic Traitors: The Whistleblower in American Literature and Culture".